# rails and coffee script if statement is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript

I'm working on a Rails app with language support for three different nationalities. The tables filled with data are implemented with JQuery. I want to translate them into all three  languages.

At the moment, I pass the current language value through a HTML data attribute:

```
<table id="companies" class="table table-striped" data-source="<%= companies_url(format: "json") %>" data-language="<%= current_language %>">
```

and save into the Coffee `Lang` variable

```
jQuery ->
  Lang = $('#companies').data('language')
  $('#companies').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    sDom: "Rlfrtip"
    bJQueryUI: true
    bDestroy: true
    bProcessing: true
    bServerSide: true
    sAjaxSource: $('#companies').data('source')
    if Lang == "ro"
      oLanguage:
        sProcessing:   "Processing...",
```

Then I check if `Lang` is "ro", "en" or "ru" and load the needed part of Coffee script.
Well at least this is the way it should work, but it doesn't.

I tried to load `data('language')` from a table in the Chrome console, which loads fine, but if the statement is not working, I always get the default English language.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When in doubt, look at the JavaScript that your CoffeeScript is compiling to; you'd see that your options hash is very broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax doesn't work. You can't put an `if` statement inside an object declaration. Your `if` needs to sit outside your list of parameters.

```
options = 
  sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
  sDom: "Rlfrtip"
  bJQueryUI: true
  bDestroy: true
  bProcessing: true
  bServerSide: true
  sAjaxSource: $('#companies').data('source')

if Lang == "ro"
  options.oLanguage = { sProcessing:   "Processing..." }

jQuery ->
  Lang = $('#companies').data('language')
  $('#companies').dataTable(options)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was really helpful comparing to down votes that I got.. I am not familiar with js or coffee.. I just spent 30 minutes to find out how to send the lang param to coffee and another 30 minutes to clear the if bug, no luck and came to SO to get the answer, thank you again.

Comment: as I wrote above, I am just worming up with js and coffee, I thought that like in rails I can use if statement wherever I have to put some conditions.. looks like it's not :)

Comment: wow, nice updated answer, would've up vote again but I can't :) thank you, nice lesson.